# Entity Framework in visual studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

How to insert compact sqlserver 4 to visualstudio 2010?

I have already installed `service pack 1 visual studio 2010` and `SQLServer2005SP4-KB2463332-x86-ENU.exe`
and `SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to download [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876).

In the past, if you wanted 64-bit to work, you had to install the 32-bit and 64-bit versions. I don't believe this is still the case, but I've never worked with it.

When you have installed it, open your VS project, add reference, and browse to the folder where the SDK was just installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the SQL Server Compact 4.0 VS 2010 SP1 tools, you can install these via Web Platform Installer